# angular-translation load translations from database

Tags: database, angular-translate

```
app.config(function ($translateProvider) {

    var ko = {
        "HELLO":"안녕"
    };

    var en = {
        "HELLO":"hello"
    };

    $translateProvider.translations('ko', ko);
    $translateProvider.translations('en', en);

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('ko');
});
```

I would want to get this **json** part below from my **database**.

```
var ko = 
{
    "HELLO":"안녕"
};
```

Which looks like this.

```
key       lang       value
=======   ========   ========
HELLO     ko         안녕
HELLO     en         hello
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do I have to use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solve this problem.
Actually I just had to look more precisely to the angular-translate documentation.

What I've done is that I used **angular-translate-loader-url**.

Instead of placing an '.json' file into the loader,
I loaded a php file that responds with json data.